# jQuery: Find data attribute with regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm attempting to grab the value of a data attribute:

```
<div class="relative-time" data-seconds="1449907467">12 December 2015</div>
```

As you see, the value is a Unix epoch time, so the value varies.

So far I've tried...

```
$(".relative-time[data-seconds='/[^0-9]+/']");
$( "body" ).data( "data-seconds", /[^0-9]+/ );
$('div[data-seconds="/[^0-9]+/"]');
$("body").attr("data-seconds");
$('*[data-seconds="/[^0-9]+/"]');
```

... But none of these return anything.

Assuming the regular expression was not correct, I swapped it out for the actual value, but there was no change.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: You want `$('.relative-time').data('seconds')` - you omit the `data-` prefix when using the `.data()` method. Note that jQuery attribute-equals selectors do not support testing against regexes. Note also that `$('body').data('seconds')` is not going to work, since the `<body>` element is not the one with the data-seconds attribute. Note further that you seem to be very confused about what the two-argument form of `.data()` does. I recommend reading the jQuery documentation rather than blindly guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Get the value

```
$('.relative-time').data('seconds');
```

Change to Date

```
new Date($('.relative-time').data('seconds') * 1000));
```

Print to console

```
console.log(new Date($('.relative-time').data('seconds') * 1000));
```

[on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7407/)

**UPDATE**

Or with a jQuery prototype function:

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.setDate = function() {
     this.text(new Date(this.data('seconds') * 1000));
     // or return value
     // return new Date(this.data('seconds') * 1000);
   }
})(jQuery);
```

To read and set Value:

```
$(".relative-time").setDate();
```

[on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7412/)

Comment: Hi MoonYard, and thank you! Part of the problem is because I'm attempting to do this within a function. Any ideas?